# Node-Fetch API GET with Headers

Tags: node.js, api

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
Node v6.4.0
npm v3.10.3

I want to send a GET Request with custom headers in this API call.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
var server = 'https://example.net/information_submitted/'

var loginInformation = {
    username: "example@example.com",
    password: "examplePassword",
    ApiKey: "0000-0000-00-000-0000-0"
}

var headers = {}
headers['This-Api-Header-Custom'] = {
    Username: loginInformation.username,
    Password: loginInformation.password,
    requiredApiKey: loginInformation.ApiKey
}

fetch(server, { method: 'GET', headers: headers})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.json()
})
.then((json) => {
    console.log(json)
})
```

The headers are not applying, I am denied access.
But within a curl command, it works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried using lower case for the header names?
The fetch spec suggests you do: [https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers)

Also: try this curl - fetch converter tool: [https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/](https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/)

Comment: @Herald, `cURL -> Fetch` converter you suggest is poor in functionality. Only headers are passed over. Everything else, any other `cURL` options are ignored.

Answer (score 12):

Let's use this bash command `netcat -lp 8081` and change the url temporarily to `http://localhost:8081/testurl`. Now, the request will still fail, but our console shows some raw request data:

```
user@host:~$ netcat -lp 8081
GET /testurl HTTP/1.1
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
user-agent: node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)
connection: close
accept: */*
Host: localhost:8081\r\n
\r\n
```

The two `\r\n`'s are n fact invisible CRLFs, the spec says, these mark the end of headers and the beginning of the request body. You can see the extra new line in your console.
Now if you rather want it to look like this:

```
user@host:~$ netcat -lp 8081
GET /testurl HTTP/1.1
username: example@example.com
password: examplePassword
requiredapikey: 0000-0000-00-000-0000-0
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
user-agent: node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)
connection: close
accept: */*
Host: localhost:8081
```

then you only need a little change:

```
// var headers = {}
//headers['This-Api-Header-Custom'] = {
var headers = {
  Username: loginInformation.username,
  Password: loginInformation.password,
  requiredApiKey: loginInformation.ApiKey
}

fetch(server, { method: 'GET', headers: headers})
```

But if you want to set some special header `This-Api-Header-Custom`, then you can't pass in nested objects and arrays, but you have to serialize your data, i.e. turn username/password/requiredApiKey data into a string. Depending on your requirements, that might be e.g. CSV, JSON, ...

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to use the Headers constructor, instead of a plain object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

```html
myHeaders = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "text/plain",
  "Content-Length": content.length.toString(),
  "X-Custom-Header": "ProcessThisImmediately",
});
```

Comment: I'm curious from where you pull Web `Header` interface in Node.js.

Comment: ```const { Headers } = require('node-fetch');```